# How can I write a query to select similar titles?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select those movies which have similar titles.
I found this, but this way it dosn't work, it gives nothing. I would like to give toy story 2, toy story 3 and others with similar title like toy soldielrs, etc.

```
$title = "Toy Story";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT title, year, poster, LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO( ".$title.", title ) as textDiff FROM movies HAVING textDiff > 60");
```

I can compare strings in PHP with this function:

```
static public function string_compare($str_a, $str_b) 
{
    $length = strlen($str_a);
    $length_b = strlen($str_b);

    $i = 0;
    $segmentcount = 0;
    $segmentsinfo = array();
    $segment = '';
    while ($i < $length) 
    {
        $char = substr($str_a, $i, 1);
        if (strpos($str_b, $char) !== FALSE) 
        {               
            $segment = $segment.$char;
            if (strpos($str_b, $segment) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $segmentpos_a = $i - strlen($segment) + 1;
                $segmentpos_b = strpos($str_b, $segment);
                $positiondiff = abs($segmentpos_a - $segmentpos_b);
                $posfactor = ($length - $positiondiff) / $length_b;
                $lengthfactor = strlen($segment)/$length;
                $segmentsinfo[$segmentcount] = array( 'segment' => $segment, 'score' => ($posfactor * $lengthfactor));
            } 
            else 
            {
                $segment = '';
                $i--;
                $segmentcount++;
            } 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $segment = '';
            $segmentcount++;
        }
        $i++;
    }   

    // PHP 5.3 lambda in array_map      
    $totalscore = array_sum(array_map(function($v) { return $v['score'];  }, $segmentsinfo));
    return $totalscore;     
}
```

But how can I compare in a SELECT query or any other way?

Comment: "LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO" is not MySQL function - you should add it DB yourself.

Comment: But you can use "LIKE" for such queries, for example: `SELECT title, year, poster FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%".$title."%'"`

Comment: in mysql you have *SOUNDEX()* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Comment: The "LIKE" is good, but if the title is more than one word it gives just those which contains all words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like queries for that:
Following example will return all the records from table customer for which customer name ends with kh

```
select * from customer where name like '%kh'
```

Following example will return all the records from table customer for which customer name start with kh

```
select * from customer where name like 'kh%'
```

Following example will return all the records from table customer for which the middle world of customer name is kh

```
select * from customer where name like 'kh%'
```

if you want more specific record then add some and/or condition in your query

I recommend you to read this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Thanks, but if I search e.g. Toy Story it gives back just those which contains both toy and story words. Didn't give for example Toy Soldiers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to define how similar things need to be to be considered a match.
But if you just wanna search for containing words, you could split your search string by whitespaces and use it in a REGEXP in your query

```
$search_array = explode(" ", "Toy story");

$query = "SELECT title, year, poster FROM movies WHERE title REGEXP '".implode("|", $search_array)."'";
```

This would probably match a lot rows, but you could make a more restrictive regular expression.

Comment: I tried this but usually give random result. If I tried to seard for "Vigyázz, kész, szörf! 2." It gives me "Az éhezők viadala - futótűz", "Need for Speed", "300 - A birodalom hajnala", etc. Sorry for hungarian example.